# Spherical metal ball contains high pressure superheated steam. If we allow it to cool in atmospheric air, at what pressure steel ball will implode?

Tags: mechanical-engineering, strength, mechanical-failure, steam, failure-analysis

Theoretically, I know that steam will start cooling slowly at constant volume to attain thermal equilibrium as per zeroth law of thermodynamics. After some time, steam will condense to water creating vacuum + water mixture because specific volume of steam is very high compared to water. This vacuum will result in catastrophic failure of metal ball. Question here is at what pressure metal will implode? Assume metal as steel and some thickness. You can take any values as per requirement to explain answer.

Comment: is this school work?

Comment: `This vacuum will result in catastrophic failure of metal ball.` ... that is not a true statement ... your questions also make an assumption that the sphere will implode

Comment: With about 14  psi external pressure, the metal would need to be thin as paper , or less.

Comment: @jsotola you can correct me if I am wrong. Question arised during brainstorming session. I came to that implosion conculsion after searching for "soda can implosion experiment". It looked similar to me. But only missing factor was pressure which I haven't found anywhere. Some related things could be "Compressive strength" of metal and "buckling criteria". But I haven't understood that because no detailed explaination given anywhere. I am also interested in PV diagram of this process.

Comment: @blacksmith37 not necessary that metal should be thin. If internal pressure become so low, then atmospheric pressure sufficient to break those vessels. So maybe answer could be atmospheric pressure is a limit for implosion but again I am not sure.

Comment: If sufficiently thin it would collapse but not likely fracture.

Comment: @Mr.Mechanical `It looked similar to me` ... it's not ...  you must consider the shape of the vessel

Comment: look at the shape chosen for vessels that can withstand huge external pressures ... https://www.amusingplanet.com/2020/03/bathysphere-worlds-first-deep-sea.html?m=1

Comment: @blacksmith37 I agree with you that thickness will play important role here. Because if we assumed negigibly small inner radius of sphere then things will be totally different. Yes, so now think it as spherical pressure vessel. Now you can think either way like what should be minimum thickness to avoid implosion. Main thing here is on what basis material will fail and what will be the pressure at that time.

Comment: @jsotola I agree that spherical vessel can withstand more pressure but in our case vacuum pressure is very high inside. We are not changing outside pressure, we are changing inside pressure in this case. Generally vessels design to withstand high internal pressure. This is opposite of that case. By the way, nice article.

Comment: no, you are changing the pressure difference ... vacuum is almost zero pressure, not high pressure

Comment: @jsotola Yes, you are right that I am changing pressure difference. I was saying that that vessels designed to handle radially outward pressure (or high internal pressure). But this pressure difference is creating opposite effect i.e. radially inward pressure (or very low internal pressure). Many things in mind like bubble-surface tension theory, Hoop stress in spherical vessels, material properties relation. Let's see what will work out!!

Comment: A vacuum can only make a 14 psi differential on this planet . Very small in terms of collapse strength.

Comment: @blacksmith37 But what is collapse strength? From where did I get that?

Comment: Several factors are undefined:, yield, tensile, thickness, diameter, geometric factor for uniformity. I know in collapse of pipes the geometric factor is important. And in some thickness range  yield dominates, and in others thickness tensile is more important. More than you want but for pipe  API Bul.  5C3  has formula but for serious external pressures like > 10,000 psi.